# Does the tropicalization of a curve remember the curve's automorphism group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups, tropical-geometry

For a tropical curve $Z$, let us call $Z_0$ this curve with its 1-valent points removed.

(Def [5] of [Joyner-Ksir-Grant Melles](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.749.9290&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) Let the **automorphism group of a tropical curve** $Z$ be a map $g: Z \to Z$ such that $g$ is a homeomorphism of on the underlying topological space of $Z$, $g$ is an isometry on $Z_0$, and $g$ preserves multiplicities. (If $Z$ is not homeomorphic to a circle, then $g$ will be a graph automorphism on the minimal graph of $Z$, taking vertices to vertices and edges to edges.)

Let's say $X$ is a curve over a field $k$. We may fix a valuation and look at either its tropicalization $\text{trop}(X)$ or its corresponding tropical hypersurface $Y := \text{trop}(I(X))$.

My question is: How are the automorphism groups of $Y$ and $X$ related? Is $\text{Aut}(Y)$ contained in $\text{Aut}(X)$?
How are the automorphism groups of $Y$ and $\text{Jac}(Y)$ related?

Comment: What do you mean by $V(X)$?

Comment: $V(X)$ suggests "variety of $X$." But maybe the OP meant the opposite, $I(X)$; i.e., the tropical hypersurface is the tropicalization of the equations defining $X$.

Comment: Apologies, I indeed meant $I(X)$, edited to reflect that.

Comment: What do you mean by ${\rm Aut}(Y)$?

Comment: Possibly the right notion of automorphisms for tropical curves is the one in: https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0446 (I guess there is an issue of graphs vs. metric graphs...)

Comment: I believe the case I want to consider is that of automorphism groups of a metric topological graph. As defined in: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.749.9290&rep=rep1&type=pdf. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: The automorphism group of an elliptic curve includes translation, but I would be quite surprised if the tropicalization of an elliptic curve had such a large automorphism group...

Comment: The paper referenced in the text: [Joyner, Ksir, and Melles - Automorphism groups on curves: Some cohomology calculations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4869).  @SamHopkins's [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372475/does-the-tropicalization-of-a-curve-remember-the-curves-automorphism-group#comment942453_372475):  [Corry - Genus bounds for harmonic group actions on finite graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0446).